# What does luck do in Vampire Survivors?

Tags: vampire-survivors

What does the Luck stat do in Vampire Survivors? I know Luck can affect the chance of getting an extra upgrade choice when leveling up, but does increasing Luck affect anything else? (Item drops, chest contents, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luck increases:

- The chance of getting a fourth option to choose from when leveling up
- The chance of getting **Pickups** other than Gold Coins or Coin Bags when destroying light sources
- The respawn rate of **light sources**
- The chance of getting more than one reward from a **Treasure Chest**
- The chance of dealing **critical damage** with the Knife, the Thousand Edge, the Bloody Tear and the Heaven Sword
- The chance of the **Pentagram** not destroying Experience Gems, Treasure Chests and Pickups
- The chance of the **Cherry Bomb** exploding
- The chance of spawning additional stage items
- The chance to be offered weapons already in your inventory

Luck reduces:

- The chance of "negative events" such as Swarms and Flower Walls

Source, [Vampire Survivors wikia](https://vampire-survivors.fandom.com/wiki/Luck).